# Streaming WebClient response with Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webclient

I need a Spring MVC controller to provide access to a webcam video stream.

My controller method uses a Spring WebClient to make an HTTP request to fetch the webcam video stream, but I am not sure how to *connect* the WebClient response to the controller method result. This is my method so far:

```java
    @GetMapping("/webcam-stream")
    @ResponseBody
    public Flux<byte[]> webcamStream() throws SSLException {
        WebClient webClient = // web client initialization

        // This does not seem to work:
        return webClient
            .get()
            .uri("/video.mjpg")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(byte[].class);
    }
```

Any advice on a proper solution?

Comment: are you using Spring MVC (servlets which are blocking) on web layer?

Comment: Yes @kerbermeister, we are using Spring MVC. Should we use Spring Webflux instead?